# Table Scrolling using keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a list of 40 rows in a table, they are nested within a div that displays 18 and hide's the rest using overflow-x:scroll.

I have created a javascript code that will allow me to select a row and navigate the rows using 'up' and 'down' arrow keys on the keyboard.

Two problems i'd like to solve are:

1. I want to start the scrolling of the table when the last of the first 18 rows is set to active.
2. If i'm on the first record and on the last record and i key in 'up' or 'down' i loose the active state of the row.

Here's a jsfiddle i'm using to try and solve the problem http://jsfiddle.net/kmcbride/cJjRH/ and below is the code.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
            <div class="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> <span>End User</span> </th>
                        <th> <span>Reseller</span> </th>
                        <th> <span>Distributor</span> </th>
                        <th> <span>Product Instance</span> </th>
                        <th> <span>Created On</span> </th>
                        <th> <span>Created By</span> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="1">
                        <td>Melita 1</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="2">
                        <td>Melita 2</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="3">
                        <td>Melita 3</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="4">
                        <td>Melita 4</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="5">
                        <td>Melita 5</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="6">
                        <td>Melita 6</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="7">
                        <td>Melita 7</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr class="openPane" id="8">
                        <td>Melita 8</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="9">
                        <td>Melita 9</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr class="openPane" id="10">
                        <td>Melita 10</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="11">
                        <td>Melita 11</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="12">
                        <td>Melita 12</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="13">
                        <td>Melita 13</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="14">
                        <td>Melita 14</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="15">
                        <td>Melita 15</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="16">
                        <td>Melita 16</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="17">
                        <td>Melita 17</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="18">
                        <td>Melita 18</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="19">
                        <td>Melita 19</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="20">
                        <td>Melita 20</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="21">
                        <td>Melita 21</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="22">
                        <td>Melita 22</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="23">
                        <td>Melita 23</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="24">
                        <td>Melita 24</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="25">
                        <td>Melita 25</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="26">
                        <td>Melita 26</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr class="openPane" id="27">
                        <td>Melita 27</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="28">
                        <td>Melita 28</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="29">
                        <td>Melita 29</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="30">
                        <td>Melita 30</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="31">
                        <td>Melita 31</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="32">
                        <td>Melita 32</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="33">
                        <td>Melita 33</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="34">
                        <td>Melita 34</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="35">
                        <td>Melita 35</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="36">
                        <td>Melita 36</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="37">
                        <td>Melita 37</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="38">
                        <td>Melita 38</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="39">
                        <td>Melita 39</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="40">
                        <td>Melita 40</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="openPane" id="41">
                        <td>Melita 41</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>WiSe00004</td>
                        <td>Enabled</td>
                        <td>7/11/2013 12:56:00PM</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="load-more-btn">Load More</div>
        </div>
```

**Js:**

```
$(".openPane").click(function() {
    if ($(".pane").hasClass('pane-open')) {
        $(".openPane").removeClass('rowActive');
        $(this).addClass('rowActive');
    }else{
        $(".pane").slideToggle(250).addClass('pane-open');
        $(".openPane").removeClass('rowActive');
        $(this).addClass('rowActive');
    };
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    var currentRow = $(".rowActive").get(0);

    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
            //arrow down
        case 40:
            $(currentRow).next().addClass("rowActive");
            $(currentRow).removeClass("rowActive");
            break;
            //arrow up
        case 38:
            $(currentRow).prev().addClass("rowActive");
            $(currentRow).removeClass("rowActive");
            break;
            //esc
        case 27:
            if ($(".pane").hasClass('pane-open') && !$(".pane").hasClass('pane-pinned')){
                $(".pane").slideToggle(250).removeClass('pane-open');
            };
            break;    
    } 

});
```

**CSS:**

```
    .table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.table table {
    width: 100%;
}
.table table th {
    text-align: left;
}
.rowActive {
    background-color: #EDF4F9!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle problem 2 you just need to check that `$(currentRow).next().length` or `$(currentRow).prev().length` is not zero before you actually move to another row.

However, I would actually just write a single function to handle selecting a new row and then call that from the event handlers for the clicks and up and down keys. That keeps you from repeating code to do the same thing three times. Inside this new function you can simply check `$(newRow).length`.

That solves problem 2. The scrolling is a bit more difficult.

First, you want to return false from your up and down key events to override the default scrolling that these keys cause.

Then, you can have the browser automatically scroll to a row by using `location.hash = '#' + $(newRow).attr('id');`, but that will put the row at the top of the table instead of waiting until the selected row is at the bottom as you prefer.

To get the scrolling behavior you want you have to add `position: relative;` to your table styling; use the `$(currentRow).position()` function to find where your row is relative to the table; and then pass some math to `$('.table').scrollTop()` to scroll there.

```
var rowTop = newRow.position().top;
var rowBottom = rowTop + newRow.height();
var $table = $('.table'); // store instead of calling twice
var tableHeight = $table.height();
var currentScroll = $table.scrollTop();

if (rowTop < 0) // row is above our current viewing area
{
    // scroll up
    $('.table').scrollTop(currentScroll + rowTop);
}
else if (rowBottom  > tableHeight) // row is below our current viewing area
{
    // scroll down
    var scrollAmount = rowBottom - tableHeight;
    $('.table').scrollTop(currentScroll + scrollAmount);
}
```

... Also, you want `overflow-y` in your `.table` styling, not `overflow-x`.

I’ve rolled all this up into a modification of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cJjRH/4/

**EDIT:** you can also check out http://jsfiddle.net/cJjRH/5/ for a slight modification that lets the default browser scrolling take back over when you're pressing up past the first record or down past the last record. It returns true from the event handler when a new row is not selected.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly :) i'm a bit new to javascript & jQuery so im fully aware of it's capabilities.